# How can I configure my SOHO Windows 7 machine to host a Minecraft Server that requires people to join the VPN prior to connecting?

Tags: security, windows-7, vpn, port, minecraft

Is that possible? Basically having some security issues with having the port open. Wondering if I can expose the Minecraft Server to a VPN only so that users will need to authenticate and join the VPN prior to being able to resolve the Minecraft Server from their home.

There is a cable modem and a router which has the port forwarded out.

Comment: @SvenW Next time I will re-phrase my question so that it is in a professional context. I mean of course it's impossible that a professional would work from home or host a game server as part of a business! Apparently this guy is also in violation? http://serverfault.com/questions/159/what-is-the-best-vpn-technology-to-implement-in-a-soho-setting

Comment: @SvenW: FAQ or not, it doesn't matter in this case. It's going to be the same question and answer with "Minecraft" replaced by another word.

Comment: @Ryan - yes, that's correct. If the question is regarding anything in a non-professional capacity, it's off-topic, even if the OP **is** a professional in his/her day job.

Comment: @Ryan, that question is three years old - a time when the site's "topics" were not clearly defined. If that question was asked now, it would be closed.

Comment: @ErikA that's not what I meant at all, what if they were a professional who's home was their office and server hosting location, just had to ask

Comment: @Ryan - in that case, it would still be on-topic for Serverfault.

Comment: @ErikA so... without knowing if I am charging money for the server or showing adverts, how did people assume that this question was off-topic? JUSTICE MUST BE SERVED :)

Comment: It was a reasonable assumption, no?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just install OpenVPN Server on the machine, configure it properly, then make your clients install OpenVPN client. You'll need to think of some way to distribute keys/passwords. Last thing, you have to configure Minecraft so it cannot be contacted from your real IP. For this You can use a firewall or maybe Minecraft's configuration itself.

Once this is all done, traffic from the outside will not reach your minecraft port. Once connected to the VPN, your minecraft clients will of course need to use the VPN IP Address and not your internet IP address to connect to the minecraft server.

Comment: How do you suppose "your clients" will be able to route packets to "the VPN address" (which would be an RFC1918 address)? They wouldn't. The only globally-routable address in this situation is the public internet IP that gets assigned to the router's WAN port by the OP's ISP.

Comment: Because they are connected by VPN. Have you ever used VPN before? Obviously the encrypted traffic will go to the public internet, but you wouldn't point your Minecraft client to the WAN IP, you'd point it to the local IP (whether it's the VPN endpoint itself or another local address)

Comment: Sorry, your last paragraph was not clear that you were talking about the minecraft clients as opposed to your VPN clients. Downvote removed.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I understand now :)

Comment: Oh, and I'm *not* a troll, thankyouverymuch. As you can see, I have legit reasons for downvoting (even though a valid reason isn't required).

Comment: Hey, I went with the info I had, a downvote with no information (;

Comment: As has been discussed in meta extensively, there's a reason the software doesn't require reasons to be submitted with down votes. If someone truly is trolling (or in other types of vote fraud), there are algorithms to pick that up and deal appropriately with the user.

Comment: I'm explaining you why I thought the downvotes were trolling, not claiming that Stack Exchange is bugged.

Comment: Fair enough. If you want to assume that all downvotes without context are trolling, fair enough. I'm just saying that not all of them are trolling.

Comment: It wasn't really the downvote, but the way it occured. The question first, then as soon as I answered, my answer too (which you later undid because there was no backing, but for a while it was suspicious), and lack of any trace left in comments. Obviously now the context is different.

Comment: There, I removed it so it doesn't bother you anymore. At least I hope.